# Prove using epsilon notation that $\lim_{n\to\infty} n\sin\frac {1}{n}=1$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

Can someone help how to prove by epsilon notation $\lim_{n\to\infty} n\sin\frac {1}{n}=1$ ?

Comment: What does $n$ go to? $n\to 1$?

Comment: No to infinity.

Comment: @HowDoIMath $n\to 1$ would give $\sin 1$, not $1$.

Comment: @user236182 you are right, I got it mixed up in my head.

Comment: Do you know an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$?

Comment: What work have you done on this problem so far?

Answer (score 2):

You need to know that for any $x> 0$, 
$$x-\frac{x^3}6<\sin x<x\qquad\text{(this is easy to prove)}.$$
Setting $x=\dfrac1n$, we obtain:
$$1-\frac1{6n^2}<n\sin \frac1n<1,$$
whence
$$0<1-n\sin \frac1n<\frac1{6n^2}, \quad\text{so that}\quad\Bigl\lvert1-n\sin \frac1n\Bigr\rvert<\varepsilon\quad\text{if}\quad n>\frac1{\sqrt{6\varepsilon}}.$$

**Proving the double inequality:**

It is a consequence of *Leibniz's theorem* on alternating series, but it can be made an exercise for high school, based on the following corollary of the *Mean value theorem*:

```
Let $f, g$  be differentiable functions defined for $x\ge a$. If $f'(x)<g'(x) for $x>a$, then $f(x)-f(a)<g(x)-g(a)$ for $x>a$.
```

Apply the corollary to $\;\sin x< x\;$ for $x>0$. You obtain successively

- $0\le 1-\cos x<\dfrac{x^2}2$, whence $\;1-\dfrac{x^2}2<\cos x\le 1$,
- $x-\dfrac{x^3}6<\sin x \le x\;$ for $x>0$ (actually, we know the right-hand side inequality is strict).

Comment: Why a downvote?

Comment: How does one prove the left inequality in the first display?

Comment: @Wojowu Consider the Taylor series for $\sin x$.

Comment: @Math1000 I suspected this is easy to prove in elementary way as well, but let's see if OP takes it.

Comment: @Wojowu: Please see my completed answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your limit as 
$$
\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}.
$$
At this point, notice that $\sin(x)=x+O(x^2)$ (see, for example, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1613919/proving-that-x-fracx36-sinx-for-0x-pi/1613923#1613923)). This means that, if you fix $\varepsilon>0$, then you can find $\delta=\delta(\varepsilon)>0$ such that
$$
|x|<\delta \implies \sin(x) \in [x(1-\varepsilon),x(1+\varepsilon)].
$$
This implies that
$$
|x|<\delta \implies \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \in [1-\varepsilon,1+\varepsilon].
$$
Therefore your limit is $1$.