# Prove : $\int_0^1 \frac{ e^{\sin^2x}}{1+x^2}\mathrm dx > 1$

Tags: calculus, inequality, definite-integrals

I want to prove the following inequality :

$$I = \int_0^1 \frac{ e^{\sin^2x}}{1+x^2}\mathrm dx > 1$$

Since I have been only introduced to elementary methods of integration, the indefinite integral appears non-solvable to me (I would be glad to see if there's a neat expression for indefinite integral).

To evaluate the integral, I used the property $\int_a^b f(x) \mathrm dx = \int_a^b f(a+b-x) \mathrm dx$ , to get  $I = \int_0^1 \frac{ e^{\sin^2(1-x)}}{x^2 - 2x + 2}\mathrm dx$
which looks much uglier. Further, the limits of integral are not symmetrical with respect to $x=0$, hence the fact that the integrand is an even function is useless.

Please tell that how can I approach this inequality. Thanks !

Comment: Perhaps you can try a Taylor approximation for $\mathrm{e}^{\sin^2 x}$.

Comment: @Gary Thanks sir for hint. But unfortunately, I haven't learnt this technique yet :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It suffices to prove that, for all $x\in [0, 1]$,
$$\mathrm{e}^{\sin^2 x} \ge 1 + x^2$$
or
$$\sin^2 x \ge \ln (1 + x^2).$$

Using [the known inequality $\sin x \ge x - x^3/6$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/803127/proof-for-sinx-x-fracx33) for all $x \ge 0$, noting that $x - x^3/6 \ge 0$ on $[0, 1]$, it suffices to prove that
$$(x - x^3/6)^2 \ge \ln(1 + x^2)$$
or
$$\frac{1}{36}x^2(6 - x^2)^2 \ge \ln(1 + x^2).$$

Letting $y = x^2$, it suffices to prove that, for all $y\in [0, 1]$,
$$f(y) := \frac{1}{36}y(6 - y)^2 - \ln(1 + y) \ge 0.$$

We have
$$f'(y) = \frac{y(y^2 - 7y + 4)}{12(1+y)}.$$
Thus, $f'(\frac{7-\sqrt{33}}{2}) = 0$, and $f'(y) > 0$ on $(0, \frac{7-\sqrt{33}}{2})$,
and $f'(y) < 0$ on $(\frac{7-\sqrt{33}}{2},1]$.
Also, $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) > 0$.
Thus,
$f(y) \ge 0$ on $[0, 1]$.

We are done.

Comment: *"Using the known inequality sinx≥x−x3/6"* Can you give a link for this ? I have seen this first time. Thanks ! The solution is then perfect.

Comment: @An_Elephant I have added the link for $\sin x \ge x - x^3/6$. More references: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1613919/proving-that-x-fracx36-sinx-for-0x-pi, and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2555669/estimate-from-below-of-the-sine-and-from-above-of-cosine, and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3905903/prove-sin-x-ge-x-fracx33

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Taylor series, use the simplest Padé approximant and
$$e^{\sin ^2(x)} \leq \frac{5 x^2+6}{6-x^2} \qquad \text{for} \quad x \in (0,1)$$ So, for an upper bound,
$$\int_0^1 \frac{ e^{\sin^2x}}{1+x^2}\,dx <  \int_0^1 \frac{5 x^2+6}{(1+x) ^2(6-x^2)}\,dx$$
$$ \frac{5 x^2+6}{(1+x) ^2(6-x^2)}=\frac{1}{7 \left(x^2+1\right)}-\frac{36}{7 \left(x^2-6\right)}$$
$$  \int_0^1 \frac{5 x^2+6}{(1+x) ^2(6-x^2)}\,dx=\frac{\pi }{28}+\frac{6\sqrt{6}}{7}  \tanh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\right)=1.02238$$

The lower bound is simple since
$$e^{\sin ^2(x)} \gt 1+x^2$$

Comment: *"use the* ***simplest*** *Padé approximant and.."*  Simplest   ? Anyway thanks , I hope I will learn these things when I will learn advanced math.

Comment: @An_Elephant. It is as simple as Taylor series but much more accurate. I am sure that you xill enjoy them as much as I do for 64+, years. Cheers :-°

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Any good references for Padé approximations?

Comment: @V.S.e.H.. I have an anwer on the site where I expain how to build them from Taylor series . https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1809229/pad%c3%a9-approximation/1809303#1809303  . If you look at my answers, I already made 473 answers with them. I love !!

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Yes , I too hope :) Thanks sir for your kind blessings.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Your last statement is not obvious for me. For what values of $x$ does it hold? Do you have a rigorous proof?

Comment: @Gary. $0<x<1$ as required for the integral

Answer (score 0):

$$e^{\sin^2x}=1+x^2+\frac{x^4}6-\frac{11}{90}x^6-\frac{71}{2520}x^8+\frac{1441}{113400}x^{10}+\ldots>1+x^2$$

So we have,
$$I = \int_0^1 \frac{ e^{\sin^2x}}{1+x^2}\mathrm dx > \int_0^1 \frac{ 1+x^2}{1+x^2}\mathrm dx=1$$

Comment: The first equality looks false. If it held for $0\le x\le 1$ then by analycity it would extend to the entire real line. For $x=\pi$ the equality fails.

Comment: How $e^{\sin^2x}=1+x^2+\frac{x^4}6+....$ ? Is this called taylor series ?

Comment: The Taylor series of $\mathrm{e}^{\sin^2 x}$ is $1 + x^2 + \frac16x^4 - \frac{11}{90}x^6 - \frac{71}{2520} x^8 + \cdots$.

Comment: @Macavity The function is analytic so the radius of convergence is equal $+\infty.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Right.  The problem seems to be that MathFail hasn't put down enough terms for you to make a conclusion that  it doesn't converge at $x=\pi$.  By your argument on the function being analytic, it should.  For e.g. of the next 6 terms in the Taylor series, 4 are negative.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, I didn't copy enough terms. @RyszardSzwarc

Comment: @MathFail From the Taylor expansion you can conclude that the inequality holds for sufficiently small $x$, but not necessarily for $ 0<x<1$. You have to use a remainder and estimate it.

Comment: @MathFail As Gary pointed out, your reasoning is not enough to prove the result.

Comment: @MathFail By the way, I did not downvote you although I criticize your answer.