# How to prove: $\sin^2 x\ge\ln(1+x^2)$ for $x\in [0,1]$

Tags: analysis, inequality, power-series

How to prove: $\sin^2 x\ge \ln(1+x^2),~~x\in[0,1]$

**My attempt:**

I try to use series to prove it.

$$\begin{align}\sin^2x=\frac{1-\cos(2x)}2&=\frac{1}2\left(1-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n\cdot4^n}{(2n)!}x^{2n}\right)\\
\\
\sin^2x&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}\cdot2^{2n-1}}{(2n)!}x^{2n}\\
\\
\ln(1+x^2)&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}x^{2n}\\
\\
\sin^2x-\ln(1+x^2)&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\left(\frac{2^{2n-1}}{(2n)!}-\frac{1}{n}\right)x^{2n}\end{align}$$

I know when $n$ is large, then $\frac{2^{2n-1}}{(2n)!}<\frac{1}{n}$, but there is an alternating term $(-1)^{n+1}$. Also the behavior for $x\to0$ and $x\to 1$ is different when compare the difference between this two series. So I stuck here. How can I proceed on this series method? Or are there other ways to prove it? Thank you!

Here is the plot for $y=\sin^2x-\ln(1+x^2)$, $y_1=y',~y_2=y''$
[image]

Comment: Isn't $\sin^2 x =\frac{1 - \cos(2x)}{2}$, not $1 - 2 \cos(2x)$?

Comment: so for the typo, I have fixed it.

Comment: Where does this come from? Is there any context or motivation for this inequality?

Comment: I don't know if it helps to compare $\exp \{ \sin^2 x \}$ to $1+x^2$ instead.

Comment: Alternating series that converge via Leibniz are bounded by their partial sums. For instance for some interval $[0,a]$ one gets the inequality chain $\sin^2x\ge x^2-x^4/3 \;?{\ge}?\; x^2-x^4/2+x^6/3\ge\ln(1+x^2)$.

Comment: Thank you! but how to conclude $a$ can be pushed to $1$ and this still hold? @LutzLehmann

Comment: You need to take more terms, first try the next higher partial sum that is an upper bound on the sine side. The difference becomes a polynomial, this will be harder to compare.

Comment: It was answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4689223/prove-int-01-frac-e-sin2x1x2-mathrm-dx-1

Comment: Thank you very much! @RiverLi

Comment: @GGplay You are welcome.